# Given a quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $AB = BC = m$ and $∠ABC = ∠ADC = 120^\circ$, what is the length of $BD$?

Tags: geometry

Given a quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $AB = BC = m$ and $∠ABC = ∠ADC = 120^\circ$, what is the length of $BD$?

I have tried cosine formula but it didn't work.

Comment: where is the figure $ABCD$?

Comment: _Hint_: draw a vesica piscis. $A$ and $C$ are the points of intersection.

Answer (score 4):

By using $\angle ABC = \angle ADC = 120^\circ$, we can draw a circle with center $B$ as the following:

[image]

Because we have $arc(ADC) = 120^\circ$ and $arc(AEC) = 240^\circ$ so this circle is valid. Now as you can see, we have radius of the circle $|AB| = |BD| = |BC| = m$.

Comment: For OP - a way of seeing this from scratch. Given the data you have the triangle $ABC$ is fixed, and the angle at point $D$ is given. There are two possibilities for $D$ - one is on the same side of $AC$ as $B$ - which I assume is excluded. In the triangle $ACD$ this tells you that $D$ lies on the arc of a circle. The issue then is how to construct the circle. Well the angle opposite to $D$ (eg at $E$ above) is $60^{\circ}$ by properties of a cyclic quadrilateral. And the centre of the circle is therefore also the centre of the equilateral triangle constructed on $AC$.